# Font size unaffected when using %?

Tags: css, fonts

Beginner at coding. Trying to use % for font size, but when I try, it looks like this no matter what number % I use: http://imgur.com/PLAzOW2

Current Code:
    
    
      
      Example

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>


<style>

.container
{    
position: relative;
vertical-align:middle;
margin: auto;
}


#random_text
{font-size:40px;
text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;
text-align:-moz-center;
text-align:-webkit-center;
font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){

$(window).resize(function() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var containerHeight = $(".container").height();
    $(".container").css("top", (windowHeight / 2 - containerHeight * 0.7) + "px");
});

var textarray = [
    "\"Example\"",
];
var firstTime = true;

function RndText() 
{
    var rannum = Math.floor(Math.random() * textarray.length);
    if(firstTime) { 
    $('#random_text').fadeIn('fast', function() { 
        $(this).text(textarray[rannum]).fadeOut('fast');
        });
        firstTime = false;
    }
    $('#random_text').fadeOut('fast', function() { 
        $(this).text(textarray[rannum]).fadeIn('fast');
    });
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var containerHeight = $(".container").height();
    $(".container").css("top", (windowHeight / 2 - containerHeight * 0.7) + "px");
}

$(function() {
    // Call the random function when the DOM is ready:
    RndText(); 
});
var inter = setInterval(function() { RndText(); }, 3000);
});//]]> 

</script>

</head>
<body><div class="container"> 
  <div id="random_text"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Does anyone know why this happens? Does anyone know a solution to fixing the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Please post a *complete* code example so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: What is your HTML code, what is the result you want? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Read the documentation. From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-size: *<percentage>
A positive <percentage> of the parent element's font size.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/dvxfktcd/), if you're trying to make the font size "*responsive*", as it grows up for bigger screens and shrinks down for smaller ones, you need to use the **view units** for width `vw`, and for height `vh`

```
#random_text {
    font-size:4vw; /* font size is 4% of the full width of the view */
```

You cannot use percentage `%` to achieve this because the `font-size:40%` means `40%` of the default font-size, not `40%` of the view.

Comment: I understand now, thank you for the help and clear explanation. It was very helpful! Thanks very much!